# How to check all checkboxes representing a DB column in Oracle ApEx with one click?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have a Tabular Form with a few columns, one of which is a numeric entry that has values 1 or 0, represented by a checkbox. 
I'd like to create a "master-checkbox" that would check all the checkboxes in this column, but it wouldn't sumbit the page, the user would have to do it manually by "Apply Changes".

I figured out that I need to use apex.item and some javascript and unfortunately, that's as far as I got.

Comment: It's quite easy to find in google: https://community.oracle.com/message/3348076

Comment: must have missed that, will look at it, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it wasn't as easy as the google results suggest.
Apex' checkbox appears to be just a cosmetic thing and the real thing is hidden.

My colleague helped me to do something like this:

```
$("td[headers=APPROVED] input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", 1); // this is the "visual" part
$("td[headers=APPROVED] input[type=hidden]").val(1); // and this is he one that gets stuff done
```

"APPROVED" is the name of the column I am manipulating.